# Find latest ScheduleState change in Lookback API

Tags: rally, code-rally

I want to display a list of US ScheduleState changes, but not all of them, only the latest change. And not only Accepted, but the current state.

I tried using ValidTo > Current, but this is not always the case, other changes might have occured, so that the ValidTo on the latest ScheduleState change is in the past.

So, is it possible to retrieve only the latest revision/ScheduleState change "automatically" via the loopback API - or do I need to do this "manually" after the load of all ScheduleState changes?

Answer (score 0):

The LBAPI uses the date 9999-01-01 to indicate that the change is last one for the set of things you have asked about. So, if you ask for information on two fields, you will get two records with a date like that. You will then have to work out what you want to know next: the last change on each field, on the last change of either field on the artefact (by looking at the _ValidFrom field).

If you want to know the current state, that's done differently with the __At field in a 'find'. But then, that doesn't tell you what/when the last changes were.